# How to retain the values of django template variables after adding it dynamically by javascript innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

1.This code is in my django template:

```
{% for var in var_list %}
<div id="button1">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" onclick="changeButton( '{{ request.session.variable1 }}', '{{ var.fields.variable2}}');return false;">Click to Modify</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

2. I am calling changeButton javascript function to change the interHTML as to change the button itself

```
function changeButton(var1 , var2) {
document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML='<div class="btn-group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="revertButton();return false;">';}
```

3. Again the old button I am restoring it by revertButton javascript function

```
function revertButton() {
document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML='<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"      href="#" onclick="changeButton( '{{ request.session.variable1 }}', '{{ var.fields.variable2}}');return false;">Click to Modify</a>';}
```

4. Now the second time I am only able to get var1 i.e session variable and not able to get var2 which is django template variable.

How to resolve it?

Comment: One way would be to add those values as data attributes on the parent DOM element.

Comment: @Brandon I can't do that because I am changing button to a button group. And on clicking one of those buttons I need to revert back.

Comment: You could wrap your button/button-group in an extra div to hold the data attributes.